# What utilities should I use to test a new notebook?

Tags: windows, laptop

I just bought a new laptop yesterday, and I would like to know what utilities to run so as to test all hardware so I can have my laptop returned for replacement if there are defective parts. The computer shop only offers 7 days replacement, and after that, I would have to rely on the 1-year warranty, which often takes weeks to process. I do not want to end up discovering a hardware defect on the 8th day and regret not having tested everything.

Thanks.

My laptop is Asus K42JK
Core i3
ATI Radeon 5145
2 GB DDR3 RAM
14" LED screen
wireless b/g/n
bluetooth
HDMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple ideas:

- [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) is good for testing the RAM (run it non-stop for more than 24 hours; we usually do 72 before declaring the RAM 'good').
- Figure out who makes your hard drive, and then go get their diagnostics software to test the drive.
- You can beat the CPU up for a few days using [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) as well.
- If you've got cash to spend, check out [Ultra-X's Quick Tech Pro](http://www.uxd.com/qtpro.shtml) software.

Comment: Thanks, I have read memtest way back when I assembled my desktop PC. thanks alot! But while using memtest for 24 hours, can I use my laptop for other things (multitask?)

Comment: Nope, Memtest runs from it's own boot source.  You want the OS out of the way so that MemTest can access/test as much RAM as possible.

Comment: ow, so that means I can't use my laptop on the first few days, (1 day for memtest, few days for Prime95)

Comment: Yup.  Or you can just trust the manufacturer did it already, believe in the warranty return process (if needed), and just go ahead and use it.  From many years of experience dealing with Asus... good luck. :(